# regular expression to match the last occurrence with specific strings

Tags: regex

can anyone tell me how to match the most close patterns between two dots. for example, I have a string "Hello. Hello. How are you.", say I want to extract the sentence including "are." so that I wrote regular expression ". (.+?are.+?\.)". However, I can only get "Hello. How are you." instead of "How are you.". Can anyone help to solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` (the metacharacter) includes `.` (the character). You could get the wanted result by excluding the `.` character like so:

```
\.[^.]*?are[^.]*?\.
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/jA5sF9/2)

Or `(?<=\.)[^.]*?are[^.]*?\.` or `\.\K[^.]*?are[^.]*?\.` in PCRE if you want to exclude the first period from the match.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. BTW, could you please tell me the difference between "[^.]*?" and ".+?"

Comment: You're welcome. `.` matches a single character that is not a newline. `[^.]` matches a single character that is not a period. `+` means *"one or more times"*, whereas `*` means *"zero or more times"*. The `?` makes the quantifier ungreedy. So `.+?` means *"one or more characters (as few as possible) that don't contain a newline"*, and `[^.]*?` means *"zero or more characters (as few as possible) that don't contain a period"*.

Comment: Hi @user4598881 if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself :) 

(There is no obligation to do this!)